# Execute python code inside a string and store it to a variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a python program that when you input a code, it executes it. It has 2 problems and I need to fix it.
I want it when you executed the code, it gets stored in a variable

I want't the result will be:

```
You executed [code] and the result was: [result]
```

now if I'm gonna do this:

```py
code = 'print("hello world")'

interpreted = exec(code)

print(f"You executed {code} and the result was: {interpreted}")
```

this shows:

```py
hello world
You executed print("hello world") and the result was: None
```

It returns none and the executed code was at the top
I want to get rid of 'none'.

2nd:
when i type print('hello') it throws an error

```py
 File "main.py", line 1                                                                                                              
    code = 'print('hello world')'                                                                                                     
                       ^                                                                                                              
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

hello world becomes an invalid syntax
how do I fix problem 1 and 2?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Use a mix of single and double quotes in your `code` statement.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: what if people want to use my code and uses ' instead of "?

Comment: Like this: `code = "print('hello world')"`

Comment: `print` function dont return anything so output will be always `none` for print statement

Comment: but i want it to get stored in a variable

Comment: Your title basically asks about `eval` but you solved that already; the real question here seems to be how to capture standard output. The second duplicate covers safer alternatives to `eval`

Answer (score 2):

the `exec` function will not return anything instead of this you can use `eval` here to get output.

But in your example `print` print wont give you any result but other function will give you result

check below code:

```
code = 'int(1.23232)'
interpreted = eval(code)
print(f"You executed {code} and the result was: {interpreted}")
```

Comment: still don't work, it gave me none when I changed the code

Comment: I want it when you executed the code, it gets stored in a variable

Comment: If you use print function it wont return anything that can not be stored in variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should do.

```
code = '''
def helloworld(): return "hello world"\n
hw = helloworld()
'''
exec(code)
r  = locals()['hw'] 
print(f"You executed code and the result was: {r}")
```